# What statement would be logically equivalent to (P exclusiveOR P) exclusiveOR P?

Tags: logic

I am not sure how to write it in text form but what would be logically equivalent to that statement in the title?

Comment: Write out the truth table for XOR and compare to one's you already know. Rewrite using the equivalence for XOR and simplify.

Comment: The exclusive OR is true when its inputs are different.  Is $P$ ever different from $P$?

Answer (score 2):

Taking it from first principles:

First use the definition for XOR.

$$\begin{align}(P\oplus P)\oplus P& =((P\vee P)\wedge\neg(P\wedge P))\oplus P\\[1ex] &=(((P\vee P)\wedge \neg(P\wedge P))\vee P)\wedge\neg((P\vee P)\wedge \neg (P\wedge P)\wedge\neg P)\\[1ex] &~~\vdots\end{align}$$

Now apply the propositional identities.

---

Alternatively; eyeball the first line ... can you see the quicker route...?

Answer (score 1):

A⊕B = AB'+A'B.
So, P⊕P is basically zero . 
And zero⊕ P is P.